# Error in calling thread: expected 'void * (*)(void *)' but argument is of type

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a structure defined in C as

```
typedef struct shape{
   int height;
   int width;

} rectangle;

// just to denote the rectangles where width > height
typedef rectangle wider;

wider all[3]={{5,10},{2,4},{7,9}};
```

and I have a function that prints the height and width

```
void funct(wider shape){
printf("height: %d, width %d", shape.height, shape.width);
}
```

Now I want to achieve this for each shape, by creating threads and so  I tried this:

```
pthread_t threads[sizeof(all)];
int count=0;
for(count=0; count <sizeof(all);++count)
{
  if(pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL, funct,(wider*)all[count])!=0)
    {
    printf("Error in creating thread: %d",count);
   break;
    }
}

int i=0;
for(i=0; i<count; ++i)
{
if(pthread_join(threads[i],NULL)!=0)
  printf ("Eroor joining: %d"+i);
}
```

However, this shows an error

```
expected 'void * (*)(void *)' but argument is of type 'void (*)(struct rectangle)'
```

I tried changing my function to

```
void funct(void *wide){
wider shape=(wider)wide;
// print same as before
}
```

but this still doesn't work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `wider shape = *(wider*)wide;`, pass `&all[count]` instead of `(wider*)all[count]`. Pointers.

Comment: Read the error message again. Is the argument to the thread function *a pointer*? Does it *return* a pointer?

Comment: Also, the `sizeof` operator returns the size of its operands *in bytes*. For your `sizeof(all)` it will return `sizeof(wider) * 3` bytes. Not the number of elements in the array. That will affect your `threads` array size.

Comment: Lastly, a pointer is not a structure, and a structure is not a pointer. Pointers and structures are not the same and are you can't just cast them to one another. [Find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and reread the chaper(s) on pointers, and especially about the address-of operator `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pthread_create()` expects a function argument that takes a `void*` as input and returns `void*`. But your function does neither. So, the compiler complains about the type mismatch.

Instead change the function:

```
void* funct(void *arg){
   wider shape = *(wider*)arg;
   printf("height: %d, width %d", shape.height, shape.width);
   return NULL;
}
```

Your argument passing has another problem. You are not passing the address of the `all[count]` but converting a `wider` into `void*`. Your `sizeof` calculation is wrong too. You should divide by `sizeof(all[0])` to get the correct number of `wider` elements in the `all` array.

```
pthread_t threads[sizeof(all)/sizeof(all[0])];
int count=0;
for(count=0; count <sizeof(all)/sizeof(all[0]);++count)
{
  if(pthread_create(&threads[count], NULL, funct,&all[count])!=0)
    {
       printf("Error in creating thread: %d",count);
       break;
    }
}
```